# Difference between TickerProviderStateMixin and SingleTickerProviderStateMixin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When I work with AnimationController it requires a vsync parameter. I have researched, should I use `TickerProviderStateMixin` or `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`, currently I still do not know what is the difference between them. Thanks if you give me an explanation about it.
References:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are using single `AnimationController` use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`.

If you need more than one `AnimationController` use `TickerProviderStateMixin`.

We need `TickerProviderStateMixin` below snippet because we have two `AnimationController`

```dart
class _TrickerExampleState extends State<TrickerExample>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller1;
  late Animation<double> fadeAnimation;

  late AnimationController controller2;
  late Animation<Alignment> positionAnimation;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember the main propose of the Ticker: Calls its callback once per animation frame. That's why the AnimationController needs a Ticker and that's why depending on the number of AnimationControllers you need one Mixin is more efficient like they said. So, if you can create all your animations with one AnimationController then use the SingleTickerProviderStateMixin. If you need more than one AnimationController then use the TickerProviderStateMixin.

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation says, they will provide [Ticker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/Ticker-class.html).

The difference is that `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` Provides one Ticker and has less `MixinApplication` than `TickerProviderStateMixin`

---

I think we have to know what is Ticker.
here a snippet explanation :
Using Flutter’s animation framework, this is achieved through a Ticker + TickerProvider.

> Ticker is the refresh rate of our animations. This is what we want to
> pause when our clock is hidden.
>
> TickerProvider, usually implemented with
> SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, is a binding between Ticker and
> external factors.

here the complete article about it : https://dash-overflow.net/articles/why_vsync/